# Admin UI messed up after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ui

Wordpress 6.0
CiviCRM 5.50.3 and 5.50.4

I upgraded Civicrm from 5.47.x to 5.50.3 last Saturday and the UI is totally messed up on the backend AND in the billing block.  I cannot figure out how to get it back to normal.  Note that no functionality is messed up, just the admin UI and the billing block.

The only error I saw in the console was related to wp-emojis, so I cleared that. There are no errors now.

I've been using Shoreditch and Shoreditch workaround for WP and when I disable those, it's still happening!

Has anyone seen this issue before or could point me in the right direction?  I have the feeling it's something simple that I'm missing, but I can't get it.

[image: Event UI]

[image: Messages UI]

Comment: Most likely you have already done that but just in case clear all caches / temporary files etc. using yourdomain.org/civicrm/menu/rebuild

Comment: Thank you.  I have cleared the cache via the UI, manually cleaned out /templates_c, even truncated all the cache tables.  In fact, every time I make a little change, I clean out all this stuff, plus my browser cache.  I've probably got the cleanest cache of anybody I know!

Comment: Also, I should add that I changed to a standard WP template, twenty twenty two, and still had the same behavior.  I'm pretty sure the problem is in civicrm code, just don't know where.